# What to use? SQL Service Broker or SQL Integration Services for remote server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, service-broker

We process approximately 200,000-300,000 questions and answers a day in a learning database through an IIS based web interface.  We'd like to move these records and their associated data to another server so we can take more time processing the data and creating more reports and charts that would otherwise impact our production server and web interface.  We intend to flatten (transform) the data so we can get a better feel for what the data indicates at any point in time.  The questions are answered 24x7 but there are "light" times around midnight and on the weekends but still quite active.

We've looked at SQL Service Broker and triggers to move and transform the data as it changes as well as SQL Integration Services to do the same but in a batch mode.  I'm not expert in either technology so I am asking for your opinion of the best approach for getting the data transformed and stored in another database on another server.

Comment: We currently use Service Broker with triggers in our production system and for the most part it works well for us. It does have some issues for us around Availability Group failovers currently that we have an open ticket to MS for.

Comment: I think both approaches will work well, but if database traffic is high then Service broker may add more workload and decrease performance. On the other hand, if you don't need to synchronize databases in real-time then using SSIS is not a bad choice

Comment: Would you say that the performance hit of Service Broker is due more to just the triggers firing and sending data or is it the "processing" that's done to transform the data before it's sent to the remote server?

Comment: Does anyone know an expert in both Service Broker and SQL Integration Services?